# Free jqGrid - more than 1 custom soft and advanced search always get into the first decleration

Tags: free-jqgrid

Seems like customSortOperations is always taking the first element out of 5 I have.

I have set on the colModel searchoptions['sopt'] = ['il','nl','em','nm'];
I have within the customSortOperations = {'posix':{buildQueryValue}.'il':{buildQueryValue},'nl':{buildQueryValue},'em':{buildQueryValue},'nm':{buildQueryValue}}

But whatever I choose from the 4 soft, it always goes into the posix buildQueryValue.

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: I suggest you to switch the supported (commertial) version of jqGrid - Guriddo jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug:

```js
if (opC === "" && p.cops != null) {
                    for (oper in p.cops) {
                        **if (p.cops.hasOwnProperty(oper)) {**  
                            opC = oper;
                            operand = p.cops[oper].operand;
                            if (isFunction(p.cops[oper].buildQueryValue)) {
                                return p.cops[oper].buildQueryValue.call(p, { cmName: rule.field, searchValue: val, operand: operand });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Should be changed to:

```html
if (opC === "" && p.cops != null) {
                    for (oper in p.cops) {
                        //if (p.cops.hasOwnProperty(oper)) {
                        **if (oper === rule.op) {** 
                            opC = oper;
                            operand = p.cops[oper].operand;
                            if (isFunction(p.cops[oper].buildQueryValue)) {
                                return p.cops[oper].buildQueryValue.call(p, { cmName: rule.field, searchValue: val, operand: operand });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```